# Streaming a video from Google Drive using HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I am trying to stream a 200MB video file from Google Drive. I have already tried embedding a 24MB file that was shared public to everyone and this worked:

```
<video controls>
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0gf7RQXoPVEa0xCSEhiRG5GNHM" type="video/mp4">
    Oops. HTML 5 video not supported.
</video>
```

When I navigate to this URL normally in the browser, a security request is shown which I have to accept. I believe this is the problem as it is blocking the download. Maybe I am missing some parameters in the URL? How do I stream larger files without Google Drive blocking the requests?

Comment: I don't think you can directly, but there are services like https://www-drv.com which act as a proxy and let you expose Google Drive, or OneDrive, content

Comment: thx! this works, it's a school project so this is a perfect solution...

Comment: cool, will add as an answer so others see it

Answer (score 26):

The method you used above is only valid for a file that is 100MB or smaller. You can actually stream Google Drive video using the HTML 5 video tag regardless of the size. It took me a while to figure this out so here it is:

- **Get the shareable link of your video.** This can be done by right-clicking the video in Google Drive and clicking the get shareable link button. Copy this link to your clipboard.
- **View the video with the shareable link.** Just paste the link you obtained from the previous step into your web browser. Please use either Firefox or Chrome for the next few steps.
- **Select the quality you want.** Use the Google Drive player and select your desired quality like 1080p or 720p. Click play to make sure the quality changed.
- **Get the absolute path of the video.** Here's the fun part: right-click on the video player and you will see the built-in menu with options like loop and stats for nerds. Right-click again and you will see the browser built-in menu with options like copy video address or save video. Select copy video address and to test it out, paste it in a new tab and see if the video plays.
- **Insert the link into your video tag.** This is the most satisfying part:

  ```
    <video width="1280" height="720" controls>
        <source src="link from Google Drive" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
  ```

Alternatively, you can use the network inspection tools that are readily available in the developer tools. They can be accessed by either right-clicking on the web page and selecting inspect element and then clicking on the network tab or by using the built-in browser menus. You may have to refresh the page and start playback before the video comes up in the network tab. Usually, it is categorised as media so you can filter out every request that refers to a media file. From there on, you will see the links to the videos and be able to copy them.

> It is important to be aware that each URL is actually associated with the client's IP. This means that the link that you get won't necessarily work on someone else's device. To combat this, you can preload the page where you get the link from for the client and then obtain the source and search for a JSON array starting `fmt_map_stream` in the Google Drive source. There, you will get four escaped links for `360p`, `480p`, `720p` and `1080p`. Copy these links and use them in your video tag. Keep in mind that this process should happen from the server side.

Additionally, I recommend using Google Photos. Google Photos allows for free storage with no limit, given that you allow Photos to compress your videos so that they don't use up your quota on Google Drive. To get started, start by uploading a video file of any size. Then, do the following:

- **Create a new album.** Name it accordingly and then drag videos or select existing content that you have already uploaded.
- **Select the sharing options.** In the top-right, there is a sharing button. Selecting that will allow you to get the shareable link of the album. ***It is crucial to ensure that only YOU can add videos to this album. Ensure that is the case above the generate shareable link.***
- **Get the shareable link to an individual video.** This is simple: right-click the video and copy the address. You should get a format like so:
  https://photos.google.com/share/SomeId/photo/SomeOtherId?key=AKey
- **Get the download link from the server-side.** The following example is a C# example that fetches the download link from any of the links in the format above:

  ```
    var source = "";

    using (var webClient = new WebClient())
    {
        source = webClient.DownloadString(link_from_above);
    }

    var chunks = source.Split(',');
    var downloadLink = "";

    foreach (var chunk in chunks)
    {
        if (chunk.Contains("video-downloads.googleusercontent.com"))
        {
            downloadLink = chunk.Replace("\"", string.Empty);

            Process.Start("iexplore.exe", downloadLink);
        }
    }
  ```

The code above simply downloads the source code from that link you obtained earlier. Then, it is split by commas since and whatever chunk contains `video-downloads.googleusercontent.com` is extracted and all `"` are replaced. In this example, Internet Explorer is launched and the link is parsed. The result would be Internet Explorer asking you to save the video. From here, you can do the following:

```
<video width="1280" height="720" controls>
    <source src="download link from source" type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

You will then be able to stream. You can also stream from VLC. The only downfall is that seeking doesn't always work since the file is technically being downloaded and played at the same time. This method is much easier than Google Drive's.

**Alternative Solution**

The Google Drive API allows you to upload and download to your Google Drive from the server-side of your web applications and even through command line and desktop applications. There is Python and .NET support and extensive documentation on how to setup your projects.

- **Enable Google Drive API.** Make sure you are signed into the Google account you wish to stream files from. You can visit [this](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/drive.googleapis.com) link to enable the Google Drive API.
- **Get an API key.** By visiting [this](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials) link, you can generate an API key to access Google Drive. You may be prompted to create a new project.
- **Get the file ID.** Access Google Drive and find the file you wish to stream. Ensure it is available to the public. Open it in a new tab and copy the file ID. It should like something like this: `https://drive.google.com/file/d/<YOUR_FILE_ID>/view`
- **Call the download link.** Your download link should be in this format:

`https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<YOUR_FILE_ID>?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&alt=media`

This was tested using a 200MB file. The download worked perfectly without any virus scanning interrupting it. Use the above link and add it to the embed code of your site.

**Another alternative**

You can use `M3U8` files to deliver content. You can split your video file into smaller segments using `FFmpeg` or any similar utility. Ensure that each segment is smaller than 100MB. Upload the segments onto Google Drive and get their shareable links. You can then change the links to their downloadable variants like so:

`https://drive.google.com/uc?id=[segment_id]`

Change your `M3U8` file by changing the links to the Google Drive download links. You can then embed the `M3U8` file into your web page like so:

```
<video width="500" height="400" controls>
    <source src="video.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>
```

This method, however, may not always work. To overcome this, you can create a web service that feeds the download stream directly to the user like so:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class SegmentController : ControllerBase
{
    private static HttpClient Client { get; } = new HttpClient();

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<FileStreamResult> Get(string id)
    {
        return new FileStreamResult(await Client.GetStreamAsync("https://drive.google.com/uc?id=" + id), new MediaTypeHeaderValue("video/MP2T"))
        {
            FileDownloadName = id + ".ts" // or + ".m2ts", depending on your media
        };
    }
}
```

Then, you can call this GET request as `/segment?id=[GOOGLE_DRIVE_ID]`. This method will essentially return the direct download stream to the client with the appropriate headers which allows the video player to stream the playlist correctly. Bare in mind, the above example is for .NET Core.

There are plenty of tutorials on how to produce `M3U8` files from existing video clips. I recommend `FFmpeg` as it is extremely simple to create these files. Apple has a guide on `M3U8` available [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/example_playlists_for_http_live_streaming/video_on_demand_playlist_construction). Since you are not live streaming, you will need a VOD (video on-demand) playlist. This method is recommended for large videos. If you do not want to compress your large videos, splitting them and delivering them in small segments will help you and you can use Google Drive to host the segments (you will need to remux your videos into `.ts` or `.m2ts` in order to split and avoid re-encoding). This is also a fantastic solution for seeking and buffering as direct downloads like the solutions above may not allow you to seek and the links also expire. YouTube uses a similar setup to deliver videos to the client.

Comment: Hi do you know how to do this from the server side?

Comment: I would recommend doing it through Google Photos. See my updated answer on Google Photos.

Comment: Excellent solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hey @Razor there's a ton of useful information here and I appreciate you taking the time to write it out X1000. I was wondering if you can expand on this point a bit: "you can preload the page where you get the link from for the client and then obtain the source". How would you go about this? I managed to do it in PHP, but the link was unique to my server's IP and not visible to the user. Attempts client-side in js were blocked by Google

Comment: Hey @Christian, that's an interesting question because I also found it difficult doing this in the web space. Since I don't have a tonne of experience with PHP, I come from an ASP.NET background, the way I would approach it (not sure how this translates with PHP) is preloading the Google Drive page from the back-end and giving your user a direct link to some server-side action or method that just feeds a direct stream to Google Drive to the user. Again, I have implemented this approach before using .NET so I am clueless as to how to achieve this in PHP, so I'm very sorry about that.

Comment: @Christian Alternatively, depending on what content you are streaming, you could look into M3U playlists. If each segment is less than 100 MB, you could just use the Google Drive direct links for each segment and you should get perfect playback, regardless of the user's IP.

Comment: @Razor Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, the links are IP-locked, so when I grabbed them in PHP, I'd get a 403 error trying to play them back in the browser. Ajax and other frontend attempts (to get a link IP-locked to the user) get me a 403 on the "/view" link as well as Google's "get_video_info" link (CORS). This seems to be a newish thing as I read about people doing it like this even 2 years ago, but they've all shut down. I've found one site that still seems to do it in php somehow: https://vidstreaming.io/ Unfortunately, most of my files are between 100Mb and 1Gb

Comment: The link seems to expire after a day of even less.

Comment: @Christian Yes, you will get 403 error. The only other way I think you can achieve streaming is if you load the Google Drive page in a hidden `iframe` on your web page. You can use basic JS to extract the source code and get the `fmt_map_stream` through JS. All this should be done on the user's side so they will have the link. Here's a link on extracting source code from `iframe` with JS. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25678366/how-to-get-full-source-code-from-an-iframe-with-javascript-or-jquery?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: @StuartClarke Yes it will expire. You will have to provide each user with a new link.

Comment: Hi Razor, thank you for your guidance. About "the link expire" - did you mean for the video file in Google Drive ? I've followed your first option in your post (the one with _"Get the absolute path of the video. Here's the fun part"_). It worked instantly, but then after a few hours when I tried it again and again, it didn't work (the round arrow progress bar keep on spinning). So, was it because the link expired ? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @karma. Yes, the link does expire after some time, hence why you are experiencing that progress bar.

Comment: Hi @Razor, thank you for your explanation. Now I understand it. BTW, I follow the OP's suggestion which using the Google Drive shared file link `uc?export=download&id="the-shared-file-id"`, it seems it work for me as I can again and again after more than 24 hours now. (My video files in Google Drive are below 4 mb).

Comment: Good to hear that you have a solution @karma. Bare in mind that my answer is suited for people with large videos that exceed 100MB. Using your method is the best option for anything below that ;-)

Comment: `<video width="600" controls>
<source src="video.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
</video>`  

This doesn't work this url structure 

`https://drive.google.com/uc?id=[segment_id]`

Comment: @AhmedAbuthwabah Are the segments less than 100 MB?

Comment: @Razor yes it is, try by your self and see

Comment: @AhmedAbuthwabah I have tried a sample playlist. VLC refuses to stream, but DVDFab and MPlayer seem to stream the video playlist. Seems to be the same issue in Firefox. You may have to create a service that redirects to the Google download link as a stream. Not sure what you are using for your web app, I will edit my answer with a sample of code to overcome this problem.

Comment: @Razor That's would be great I have tried it with  the html5 video player and jwplayer

Comment: @AhmedAbuthwabah I have updated the question with a .NET Core example. I'm unsure if this is what you are using, I don't have sufficient knowledge in PHP or other technologies outside of ASP.NET. I hope this helps.

Comment: @Razor Thank you man, I managed to get it work by creating a web server as you mentioned in your answer, however sometimes i get 403 error with this message `We're sorry… but your computer or network may be sending automated queries` do you have any idea why is that?

Comment: @AhmedAbuthwabah That's good to hear. The error you mentioned is quite odd because I use this method all the time and nothing like that ever happens. The error typically occurs if too many requests are being made from the same IP address. This makes sense since your playlist is being buffered and segments are being downloaded ahead of time, hence why you are getting this error.

Comment: Try to play your video in VLC or a different video player and check the log. I have used this method before using an external media player (with about 40,000 segments) and Google has no problem whatsoever.

Comment: Hello @Razor, I've been following the instructions detailed in your answer and decided to opt into using the Google Photos route of streaming videos. However, I was stumped on how I could convert the C# example of fetching the download link into Python so I could use it for my Django project. Do you happen to have any insight on how I can go about doing this?

Comment: Hey @bimmui, unfortunately I'm unsure about a python/Django implementation, I work a lot in .NET with C#. I can, however, explain what is happening though, maybe that can help you with an implementation. So the part with the `WebClient` simply downloads the HTML source code from the Google Photos URL. Maybe search for a Python implementation to download the HTML source from a web URL? The splitting of the string should be quite simple to implement with Python, as well as replacing the double quotes. You can ignore the `Process.Start` call, that was just for testing out the download link.

Comment: `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/<YOUR_FILE_ID>?key=<YOUR_API_KEY>&alt=media` Works but this will made my API key public is there any safer way to get it working?

Comment: Yes, take a look at the code sample I provided. You can completely hide your API key on the server and just send the user a file stream using your link. The only endpoint the user will see is yours and not the Google API.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can directly, but there are services like [www-drv.com](http://www-drv.com) which act as a proxy and let you expose Google Drive, or OneDrive, content.

*I have some concern re their service as the FAQ is a little unclear how much access to the GDrive/OneDrive they require, it's not obvious if you have to let them access from the root down (which would be a no-go for me) or if you can select a single directory (and sub-directories). I'd emailed them in the past asking for clarification but no response ... just wanted to include that caution.*

Comment: I took a secondary account where no other stuff is on google drive. I would never trust in such a service.