# How do you stream Large Google drive Videos with HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, google-drive-api, html5-video

I am building a web application using Django where I want to place a google drive shareable video link and have it played with the HTML video tag.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [blogpost](https://sourcey.com/articles/html5-video-streaming-from-google-drive), Google automatically encodes uploaded videos into lower bitrate FLV files for playback using Flash via the Google Drive Viewer. It means you can actually stream Google Drive video using the HTML 5 video tag regardless of the size.

```
<video controls="controls">
    <source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0JMGMGgxp9WMEdWb1hyQUhlOWs" type='video/mp4'/>
</video>
```

Check this related [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880756/stream-video-from-google-drive-in-html-5-video-tag) for more details.

Comment: Trying it out like this, the video doesn't play and on inspecting I get the following warning: Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=0B0JMGMGgxp9WMEdWb1hyQUhlOWs with MIME type text/html. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5629709824032768 for more details.

Comment: Just change the source of the drive to your own drive.

Comment: Please what exactly do you mean by "the source of the drive"?

Comment: The `src` attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a guide on streaming large videos in Google Drive without using Drive's built-in media player. Jess had provided a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880756/streaming-a-video-from-google-drive-using-html5-video-tag/52397246#52397246) to it in his answer. My answer covers Google Drive, Google Photos and the Google Drive API.