# video from google drive open new tab

Tags: google-api, drive

how remove "open new tab" button ? 
The embedded link directly from Google Drive doesn't seem to allow you to remove the button that opens the video in a separate tab nor customize the appearance of the player.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace "videoID" in the link with your video ID. (to find it - right click on the Google Drive video, get shareable link)

```
<video>
<source src="https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=videoID" type='video/mp4'>
```

other[solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43880756/stream-video-from-google-drive-in-html-5-video-tag/52397246#52397246)