# How to get a true video url for exoplayer from google drive shared video link?

Tags: javascript, android, html, google-drive-api, exoplayer

I want to play video from google drive in exoplayer. I copied the shareable link. But this link leads to google drive video player page. I have checked shareable link response, it contains link for video thumb image and also the video link. But this video link is calling any code further to play the video. I want to get or more specifically extract the true video playable link from the response. Here is the code portion from the response which contains important links,

```html
<meta name="referrer" content="origin">
<title>KOB-S3-E1.mp4 - Google Drive</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="KOB-S3-E1.mp4">
<meta property="og:type" content="video.other">
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Google Drive">
<meta property="og:url" content="https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eqNQOwDzDDjHizpUz-sB86VK4LisqGu1/view?usp=sharing&amp;usp=embed_facebook">
<meta property="og:image" content="https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/eqNekxifrzidbBB-SzJbdJJ1xcOY6NFgR_0wIXHAnX-uHLO3FfUmgt-AokDallwbAXI=w1200-h630-p">
<meta property="og:image:width" content="1200">
<meta property="og:image:height" content="630">
<meta property="og:video" content="https://video.google.com/get_player?docid=1eqNQOwDzDDjHizpUz-sB86VK4LisqGu1&amp;ps=docs&amp;partnerid=30&amp;cc_load_policy=1">
<meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash">
```

The image thumb link is working, but the I can't find the link which I can use to play video in exo player android app.
This is the original shareable link:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eqNQOwDzDDjHizpUz-sB86VK4LisqGu1/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Drive video's are not designed to be streamed directly as you want - it can be done, see below, but you need to be aware that, as this is not the intended use, you could find it stops working overnight if Google Drive update the way they have architected or deployed their solution.

With the above caveat in mind, there are approaches that will allow you extract the original video URL - see this answer for a good example which outlines a number of approaches: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52397246/334402

One thing to be aware of - your original hosted video is actually being delivered using ABR streaming protocols, which means the video is copied into different resolutions/bitrates on the server side and each copy broken into chunks. The player can decide which resolution to download for the next chunk based on the current network conditions and player capabilities. See, for example, the 'quality' options for your video by looking at the settings:

[image]

Depending on the approach you use you may need to be aware of the particular URL for the specific resolution you want.

If you simply want to play the video back in an app and it does not need to be via ExoPlayer you may find it much easier to simply use the standard embed code within a Webview in your app.